# What Attribute Would I Add To CSS To Make It Start At A Particular Place On The Page?

Tags: html, css

So my little webpage has a little piece of content in the upper left corner that does not go all the way to the bottom of the page. I want my next set of content thats a div called leftText to automatically start after the content in the corner. Right now it starts beside it like it is supposed to, but then after it gets lower than the the content in the corner, the text starts appearing under the content in the corner, instead of beside it. Is there something simple I can add to my css to make it no longer go under?

```
.leftText {float:left; background-color:green; width:12%; height:7%; border: 4px solid white; }
```

Comment: Instead of using float you could have both elements using `display: inline-block;` and then they would stay side by side

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks JensV, the `display: inline-block;` did the trick!